# JavaScript Calculation Help (Multiplying Time)

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I was using to generate a calculation from two inputs but am having trouble generating the result I need.

I have two inputs (let's call them input1 and input 2). When you enter in a value, it calculates it based on the following:

**(input1 x 0.156$) x ( (input2 x 15 seconds) x 4.2) x 12 months**

My original code is as follows:

```
var calculation = function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('people').value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById('stories').value;
  var result = Math.floor(input1 * 0.2 * input2 * 30);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  return false;
}
```

It's the var result that I'm having difficulty changing (the code above was for a different calculation). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code looks fine to me, but how are you calling this function?

Comment: technically it works but it's a different calculation than what I need now. I tried var result = Math.floor(input1 * 0.2 * (input2 * 30) * 4.2 ) * 12; but it spits out a very large result, so I think it's incorrect.

Comment: Well your "new" calculation is basically adding an extra `* 4.2 * 12` to the mix, making roughly a 50x increase to the previous number...

Comment: I noticed that, too. I clarified in the thread below a little more specifically what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you are not implementing your formula correctly, try changing it to:

```
var result = Math.floor((input1 * 0.156) * ((input2 * 15)*4.2)*12);
```

It also will be good to tell us what 4.2 stands for.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdgox87p/5/)

Comment: Multiplications are commutative, meaning *it doesn't matter* what order they're in. `Math.floor(input1 * 0.156 * input2 * 15 * 4. * 12)` will be just the same.

Comment: The 4.2 is meant to be 4.2 weeks and the 12 = months.

Comment: I figured out how stupid i was being the moment i clicked save edit, i removed it now ^_^

Comment: so 15 second * 4.2 weeks * 12 months = 756 what? some more explanation on what are you trying to achieve might help.

Comment: Apologies. OK, here's what I'm going for..(input1 x $0.156) x ((input2) x 15 seconds) x 4.2 weeks) x 12 months = result

Comment: @Freddy But you already have that - remember that multiplications can be in any order.

Comment: Ok gimme a moment and i'll look into it, do you have any test cases ?

Comment: Much appreciated! I don't have any test cases, though.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working JSFiddle hope that satisfies your needs.

Comment: @VladimirDrenovski Fantastic! Thank you! Sorry to be a mooch here at this point, but can the result use commas (50,000 instead of 50000)? Cheers!

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle and it format's it as you want, but make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript regarding browser supportability. I hope to have satisfied you :) also sorry for the late answer :)

Comment: @VladimirDrenovski Thanks so much! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`var result = Math.floor((parseInt(input1) * 0.2) * (parseInt(input2) * 30));`

by converting the `input1` & `input2` to numeric

Comment: Multiplication does that already, and the second argument to `parseInt` is NOT OPTIONAL.